# Как обновить частично данные в таблице базы данных ? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, база-данных

Есть метод update_user, который обновляет личную информацию о юзере. Но в метод порой не всегда будет передаваться полные данные. Как сделать так, чтобы существующее значение не перезаписывалось Null ?

```
class UsersDb(UsersDbAbstract, SqliteConnection):
    
    @staticmethod
    def update_user(user_id, **kwargs):
        username = kwargs.get('username', None)
        first_name = kwargs.get('first_name', None)
        last_name = kwargs.get('last_name', None)
        UsersDb._make_request('UPDATE `Users` SET `username`=?, `first_name`=?, `last_name` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?;',
                              params=(username, first_name, last_name, user_id,))# если какое-то значение будет None, то таблицу запишется Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю метод конструирования запроса

```
def update_user(user_id, **kwargs): 
        username = kwargs.get('username', None)
        first_name = kwargs.get('first_name', None)
        last_name = kwargs.get('last_name', None)
        
        request=''
        if username!=None:
             request+=f'`username`={username},'
...
        request=[:-1] #обрезали зпт
        UsersDb._make_request('UPDATE `Users` SET '+request+' WHERE `user_id` = ?;')
```

Вариант множественных запросов считаю не целесообразным